# Cosine Similarity Metric Learning

Tags: python, tensorflow

My question is do we need to define a transformation matrix  as in the equation below and initialize it if the two vector is the output feature vector from my  any deep neural network. I mean, because I think the `A` is already embedded in the features that I got from my network so no need to code it.

So for example:

#### Definition of Cosine similarity metric from [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/220745463_Cosine_Similarity_Metric_Learning_for_Face_Verification) is:

Cosine similarity function: [image]

#### And my implementation without considering the `A` transformation matrix is  :

[image]

So is this implementation right or we need to define an `A` transformation matrix and initialize it and train it as well?

Comment: You can do whatever you want. Learn on top of your network or keep the raw output.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. And if I want to include the A transformation matrix, how I can handle that in tensor flow. We will have a problem with X^T since the diminution of X is [None, m]  and  it is not possible to know the diminution of None before begin training and run the session. So how the transpose will be implemented?